# Converting a hover menu to touch devices (jsFiddle)

Tags: hover, touch

jsFiddle link for running demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dahAG/

In order to make this hover menu compatible on touch devices, it needs to have a function that collapses the menu after it has been pressed open on a touch device by allowing the user (on the touch device) to press anywhere on the screen outside of the menu. Currently, on touch devices, the only way to collapse the menu after it has been opened is to press on the menu again. What is the best way to accomplish this?

This hover menu simply uses CSS3 transition effects, no JavaScript—but I am more than happy to integrate some if that's the preferred method.

**HTML**

```
<section onclick="">
    <nav class="menu left" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="p1"><img src="images/submenu.gif" alt="">
        <ul id="p1">
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Products</a><b></b></li>
            <li aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Services</a><b></b></li>
            <li aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Demonstrations</a><b></b></li>
            <li aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Menus</a><b></b></li>
            <li aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Layouts</a><b></b></li>
            <li aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Contact</a><b></b></li>
            <li class="last" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Privacy</a><b></b></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width:880px) {
    .menu {
        width:200px;
        }
    .menu.center {
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:left;
        }
    .menu.right {
        margin:0 0 0 auto;
        text-align:left;
        }
    .menu img {
        display:block;
        }
    .menu ul li {
        display:block;
        margin-bottom:-40px;
        -webkit-transition:0.5s;
        -moz-transition:0.5s;
        -o-transition:0.5s;
        transition:0.5s;
        }
    .menu ul li:last-child {
        margin-bottom:0;
        }
    .menu ul li.current {
        display:block;
        z-index:10;
        }
    .menu:hover ul li {
        margin-bottom:0;
        }
    }
```